# Avalonia секунды в TimePicker

Tags: avalonia

C# Avalonia MVVM. Нужен TimePicker, который показывает часы, минуты и секунды. Хочу разместить его во View формата .axaml для выбора пользователем времени для таймера. Кроссплатформенность Avalonia должна оставаться. Или только создавать какой-нибудь свой CustomTimePicker? Наверняка не надо изобретать велосипед и уже кто-то делал и есть готовое решение. Может из дополнительных библиотек? Чуть ранее, например, находил аналоги MessageBox в NuGet.